# Mongoose statics: running into issues when adding checks to custom findById

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I noticed that I havce a lot of code like this:

```js
const doc = await Model.findById(id);
if (!doc) throw new Error('some error');
if (doc.date < someDate) throw new Error('some other error');
```

So I figured, let's make my own `findById` method which does all these checks for me and only if all checks pass, it'll return the query `findById` normally returns. Something like this:

```js
schema.statics.myFindById = function (id) {
    const query = this.findById(id).lean();
    const document = await query.exec();
    if (!document) {
        throw new Error(`invalid id '${id}'`);
    }
    if (new Date(document.date) < new Date()) {
        throw new Error(`document expired`);
    }

    return this.findById(id);
};
```

But this code will not run, since it contains an `await`. And when fixing that by making the function `async` like

```js
schema.statics.myFindById = async function (id) {
    const query = this.findById(id).lean();
    const document = await query.exec();
    if (!document) {
        throw new Error(`invalid id '${id}'`);
    }
    if (new Date(document.date) < new Date()) {
        throw new Error(`document expired`);
    }


    return this.findById(id);
};
```

`myFindById` suddenly returns a promise, NOT the query `findById` normally returns. And when using

```js
return await this.findById(id);
```

The query **result** is returned, which is obviously different than the query itself.

Any ideas on how to tackle this?